# Enabling Smart Touch remote as mouse/touch pad input

Tags: flash, mouse, touchpad, samsung-smart-tv

In the web browser that comes with the Samsung ES8000, mouse/touch pad support is possible through the Smart Touch remote.

I'm developing a Flash-based app and need to support mouse input. The TV allows for external mouse input, which I can get working through `<mouse>y</mouse>` in `config.xml`.

It also, apparently, exposes an external mouse input API, which I haven't played with:

- http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_3.1/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Interactive_Remote_API/mousepad

Telling my users they have to connect an external mouse to use the app is obviously not nice. Is it possible to enable the Smart Touch remote as a mouse/touch pad in other apps? I've searched the Samsung Guide docs and Google but cannot find any reference to it.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Did you find any solution? Let me know if you find. Thanks

Comment: @Sarah, no, no solution yet. However, I have since discovered that higher range Samsungs (that the Smart Touch remove comes with) also come with gesture control enabled for free on mouse-enabled apps. Simply hold one hand stationary beside your shoulder in front of the TV (with camera) and a mouse pointer will appear that you can control using gesture.